# con el comando cd ¿Cómo voy "x" carpetas atrás y luego "y" carpetas en otra dirección?

Tags: php, vscode, powershell, composer, stripe

muy buenos días como dice en el titulo a modo de pregunta ¿Cómo puedo ir unas "x" carpetas atrás hasta un punto origen y de ahí otras "y" carpetas adelante? (siendo "x" y "y" números reales enteros positivos distintos de cero y distintos entre si), verán estaba en vs code implementado una extensión de stripe para php, como es bien sabido casi todas las extensiones o librerías usan composer, este usa un archivo llamado autoload que esta en la carpeta vendor pero mi problema es que la carpeta con los archivos .php de stripe esta metido en 3 o 4 carpetas. aqui la imagen de la carpeta de stripe:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en el código esta esto:

```html
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
```

y la carpeta de vendor esta así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aun que los dos estén en la misma área de trabajo la de stripe tiene varias carpetas y adentro están los archivos php necesarios, aqui la pregunta sigue en pie:

¿Cómo puedo ir unas "x" carpetas atrás hasta un punto origen y de ahí otras "y" carpetas adelante?

agradezco de antemano su(s) respuestas

Comment: ¿Buscas hacer esto que dices dentro del código PHP?

Comment: en efecto, de hecho en la linea de request es donde quiero poner la nueva dirección

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define una constante  al inicio de tu proyecto

```html
$HOME=$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
define("RAIZ",$HOME);
```

Ahora todas las direcciones las tratas desde esa dirección

```html
require  RAIZ .'/micarpeta/micarpeta2/documento.php';
```

Si hay una direccion muy larga que es recurrente (la utilizas mucho) creas una constante para ello

```html
$HOME=$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
define("RAIZ",$HOME);
define("STRIPE",RAIZ."/carpeta1/carpeta2/carpeta3/stripe/");
```

la utilizas de la siguiente manera

```html
 require  STRIPE .'/documento.php';
```

Recuerda que estas constantes las defines una vez y estarán disponibles en toda tu aplicación. crear un documento **constantes.php**

así te olvidas de estar escribiendo

```
"../../.././../../carpeta/documento.php"
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu aporte lo voy a tener presente en mi libreta de aprendizaje para que no se me olvide gracias

Comment: de nada. para eso estamos